# Prestashop - Show the full name in Orders List page in Backoffice

Tags: prestashop

As you all know in the backoffice>Orders It show only First letters of the first name and the last name ! I'm wondering how could I show the full name ! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `AdminOrdersController` for that, which is located at `YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php`.

First make a override file with same name on this location:
`YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/override/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php`

Now on your override file define the override class like this:

```php
class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore
{
    // your override code here
}
```

now copy the whole constructor method ( `__construct` ) and paste it in your file, in my case it was in between `line 31` and `line 147`.

then find and move this line:

```php
parent::__construct();
```

to the beginning of the constructor method. after that find and change this line:

```php
CONCAT(LEFT(c.`firstname`, 1), \'. \', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`,
```

to

```php
CONCAT(c.`firstname`, \'. \', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`,
```

save the file. and finally just remove this file `YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/cache/class_index.php`

that's it. you should see full name in your backend order page. hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

find the following file `YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php` and replace

```
CONCAT(LEFT(c.`firstname`, 1), \'. \', c.`lastname`) AS `customer,
```

with

```
CONCAT(LEFT(c.`firstname`, 100), \'. \', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`,
```

Comment: Why did you answer later than accepted answer and with a worse solution? :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved, line 62 in controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php has to be rewrite as follows:

CONCAT(c.`firstname`, \' \', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`,